# Play 2 with JSON

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I am new to using Play2 Framework. Here is a simple controller that i have writen

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;
import views.html.*;
import models.*;
import java.util.*;
import play.libs.Json;
import  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;


public class Users extends Controller {

      @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
      public static Result register() {
          JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
          String firstName=json.findPath("first_name").asText();
          String lastName=json.findPath("last_name").asText();
          String mobileNumber=json.findPath("mobile").asText();
          String address=json.findPath("address").asText();
          String userName=json.findPath("user_name").asText();
          String password=json.findPath("password").asText();

          ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
          result.put("status", "FAILIURE");
          result.put("message", "Missing parameter [name]");
          return ok("meow");

  }

   public static Result login() {
    return TODO;
  }

  public static Result logout(final Long id) {
    return TODO;
  }

}
```

I am hitting with curl

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -X PUT -d "{"first_name": "simon","last_name": "bolliver","mobile": "12345","address": "23 Donwton","user_name": "simon","password": "levy"}" http://localhost:9000/user/register
```

I am getting a NullPointerException on the second line. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Your controller looks fine, but you need to set the `Content-type` header on your curl request and wrap your `-d` parameter with `'` instead of `"`.

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"first_name": "simon","last_name": "bolliver","mobile": "12345","address": "23 Donwton","user_name": "simon","password": "levy"}' http://localhost:9000/user/register
```

Answer (score 0):

For happy development try use in `chrome` [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/). Or if you like `consoleway` use [httpie](https://github.com/jkbr/httpie)